# Possible to remove remaining foreclosed mortgage debt off my credit report?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit-report, foreclosure, california

A little while ago, I asked a [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/foreclosure-debt-still-on-the-credit-report) where the consensus was that the bank won't be coming after me for the remainder of the money after the house was foreclosed on.

Seeing how they can't come after me, why is that amount still on my credit report?  And more importantly, is there a way to remove them from the credit report?

Comment: Have you talked to a lawyer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the loan amount is showing is because it is a default - the fact that you live in a non-recourse state doesn't change the fact that a loan obligation that had your name on it was defaulted upon.

I don't think there is much you can do now given that your name was still on the mortgages.